# Is it possible to dock a UML diagram like a tool window?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use the IntelliJ database plugin's ability to draw a diagram of a database schema.

Unfortunately, by default, the diagram functionality seems to lay out diagrams as code editor panes.

I don't want to split the editor pane - I want to dock the diagram, like a tool window - so I can control it and lay it out the way I want like any other tool window.

Is there a way to dock database diagrams into a tool window?

Comment: Editor splitting is not enough?

Comment: The answer is No, request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, as per @CrazyCoder.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178091